# How can I create a callback function for jQuery's trigger() function?

Tags: jquery, callback, eventtrigger

I use `trigger()` to force a form submission and I need to execute a function after the form submission is complete. I assume the only way to do this is with a callback function, but it seems that `trigger` doesn't allow for callback functions. How can I achieve the same result? I want something that would be equivalent to the following:

```
$('#fileUploadButton').trigger('click',function(){
    // my callback function code goes here.
});
```

Comment: As events are synchronous, it does'nt make sense to do this. Just add the next line after the first, and it will get executed in the single thread. If you're submitting a form, the page reloads, and there is no callback for that.

Comment: True, but the form is being submitted in an ``iframe``, so I need to know when it is through being submitted.

Comment: Then you probably need a custom event that sends a callback to the parent window when the form has submitted, and suddenly it became really complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the form submit as an AJAX-Request. If the request is succeed you can do anything. Another alternative is to use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to communicate between two frames.

example for an AJAX-Request:

```
$(":submit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : $(this).parents("form:first").attr("action"),
        data : $(this).parents("form:first").serialize(),
     })
     .done(function(data) {
         // submit is done: do anything
     })
});
```